# Android - playing multiple MediaPlayers simultaneously not working on Samsung

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, samsung-mobile

I want play multiple sounds simultaneously in my app. So I create multiple instances:

```
mMediaPlayerTracker1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
mMediaPlayerTracker1.start();
```

It's working OK on different devices with different Android versions. But it's not working on Samsung devices (with Android 5.0). It will only play one sound (not all of them).

Do you know where can be a problem? What is different in Samsung devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ExoPlayer: https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html

You can try modifying the demo app https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v1/demo

and see if that works for you.

ExoPlayer v2 is on the horizon and has less boilerplate (see the demo app for it here: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/dev-v2/demo)

and some neat audio features:
https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/exoplayer-2-x-new-audio-features-cfb26c2883a#.u18xtc6c9